# Comportamiento inesperado en el bucle while de JavaScript, al ejecutarlo en la consola del navegador

Tags: javascript, while

> Por favor, lea cuidadosamente este planteamiento.

### Un poco de contexto

En unas pruebas que estaba realizando me tropecé accidentalmente con un comportamiento inesperado, al menos para mí, del bucle [while](/questions/tagged/while).

Por ejemplo, si defino las siguientes líneas:

```js
let i = 0;

while (i < 4) {
  console.log(i);
  i = i + 1;
}
```

O esta otra forma, cambiando `i = i + 1` por `i++`:

```js
let i = 0;

while (i < 4) {
  console.log(i);
  i++;
}
```

Funciona como se espera devolviéndome la siguiente salida:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Sin embargo, cuando las escribo directamente desde la consola del navegador (probado en Firefox y Chrome) o directamente desde la terminal con **NodeJS** (sin utilizar *`archivo.js`*) el resultado cambia.

Por ejemplo, si escribo las líneas:

```js
let i = 0;

while (i < 4) {
  console.log(i);
  i = i + 1;
}
```

Me devuelve la siguiente salida:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Pero, si cambio `i = i + 1` por `i++` el resultado vuelve a cambiar. Por ejemplo, en las siguientes líneas con el cambio mencionado acá:

```js
let i = 0;

while (i < 4) {
  console.log(i);
  i++;
}
```

Devolviéndome la siguiente salida:

```
0
1
2
3
3
```

#### Pregunta

**¿A qué se debe este comportamiento?**

Comment: Sera algo del navegador? u otra basura en tu consola? porque aca, no pasa...

Comment: Ejecutándose desde el Snippet funciona como se espera, pero si se ejecuta directamente desde la consola del navegador o la terminal adopta ese comportamiento.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El último valor lo pone console por su cuenta como último valor asignado.
Compruébalo de esta manera

```
let i = 0;

while (i < 4) {
  console.log("valor de i: "+i);
  i++;
}
```

Verás que la salida es

```
valor de i: 0
valor de i: 1
valor de i: 2
valor de i: 3
3
```

Si pones `console.log(i)` verás que es `4.`
Es decir es un comportamiento normal.
Fíjate que si pones en consola `a=14`, aparece el `14` sin que se haya ejecutado una sentencia `console.log`

Comment: Otra manera de notarlo, rápidamente, es que hay una _flechita_ apuntando hacia la izquierda (comprobado en Brave y Firefox).

Comment: Hola, Juan. Voy realizar la prueba que me indicó.

Comment: Juan, muy buena observación al igual que la de @padaleiana.